# Restricting null in object construction in java

Tags: java, hashcode, pojo

Suppose the constructor of a class (say class A) has a constructor which throws exception is any of the parameter(say class A has two member variables String fieldOne and String fieldTwo) is null.

Will this cause any problems as I see that null arguments are also used in hashCode() implemention:

Here is the hashCode() method:

```
public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((fieldOne== null) ? 0 : fieldOne.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((fieldTwo== null) ? 0 : fieldTwo.hashCode());
        return result;
}
```

Note: Class A is immutable , class A is `final`, there are no setters for member variables. Also the member variables are `final`

Comment: I do not understand the problem. If `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` are never be null, you do not have to check for it.

Comment: If you throw an exception on contruction, is your object contructed?

Comment: You won't be able to call the hashCode method if there is a null argument because the constructor will throw an error

Comment: Why should checking an object for null cause any problems?

Comment: @TMichelsen OP is mentioning only the constructor, values can still become null through the setters.

Comment: The code snippet is generated by eclipse. I think we can remove null condition for fieldOne and fieldTwo

Answer (score 2):

That would be fine: there will be a small amount of redundancy in the ternary conditionals, that's all.

You'd be advised to leave the checks for `null` intact (as other functions may assign `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` to other objects, including `null`), unless you mark the fields `final`.

Comment: Class A is an immutable class. fieldOne and fieldTwo are final variables

Answer (score 1):

I would leave the the null-checks if:

1) You have setters

2) There is a possiblity that someone other than you will add a new constructor without null-checks in the future